# Creator | Admin | moderator permission testing with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have trouble with understanding of RSpec testing. Read docs, tutorials, but still dont really understand, how to test following case.
I need to test that access to editing allowed only for note's creator, admin and moderator.
btw, it works in browser, but i want to learn how to write test for things like this.

Controller:

```
  before_action :set_note_with_permissions, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { }
      format.html {  }
    end
  end

  def set_note_with_permissions
    current_note = Note.find(params[:id])
    if current_user && (current_note.user.id == current_user.id || current_user.moderator? || current_user.admin?)
      @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    else
      # redirects / flashes / etc.
    end
  end
```

FactoryGirl fixtures:

user:

```
FactoryGirl.define do


factory :unconfirmed_user, class: :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@example.com" }
    name "name"
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    role "user"
    factory :user do
      after :create, &:confirm
      factory :moderator do
        role "moderator"
      end
      factory :admin do
        role "admin"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

note:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :note do
    content "Content"
    association :user, :factory => :user
  end
end
```

and my logic of test is:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe NotesController do
  describe "edit action" do
    context "when try to edit note" do
      it "is your note" do
        note = create(:note) # => note.user.id == 1 (couse of association)
        user = create(:user) # => user.id == 2
        sign_in user
        get "notes/#{note.id}/edit"
        expect(response).not_to render_template("edit")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but as you can expect it does not working with

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"notes/1/edit", :controller=>"notes"}
```

i dont ask you to write code for me. Just point to necessary docs and technologies. Do i need Copybara for it, or it is possible with pure RSpec?

Comment: does it work when you try accessing it on browser?

Comment: Yes, it works, but i really want to learn such powerful thing as TDD for future :)

Comment: just making sure your problem is actually in the test instead of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you are receiving, I believe your issue is in how you are calling `get`. Rather than passing in the URL as a string, you should be passing in the name of the action as a symbol. So in your case you can change

```
get "notes/#{note.id}/edit"
```

to

```
get :edit, id: note.id
```

and it should work.

As you can see, you can pass in additional parameters for the controller action as a hash. You can see examples of this in the first and last examples [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec).

Comment: Thanks, will try your solution as soon as I get to computer!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped :)